# Display Array with additional input in between

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array with some numeric values. I want to display them but I also have a user input which should be displayed after the respective element in the array. My approach works fine but seems really overcomplicated to me. I created a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/sjoy8p59/1/

```
var numbers = [2, 4, 8, 12, 42, 120, 612, 69];
var input = 32;
var flag = false;
var output = "";

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] < input) {
        output += numbers[i]+", ";
    } else {
        if (flag == false) {
            output += input + ", ";
            flag = true;
        } else {
            output += numbers[i]+", ";
        }
    }
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

So the value `32` from `input` should be displayed after the `12` and before the `42` from the array. I use a for loop and a boolean with an if clause to detect whether the Array element is larger or smaller than the input and then add it all together and display it.

How can I do it better and cleaner?

EDIT: I figured out there is a mistake in my code because it skipped one element in the array

Comment: should I post all the code from the fiddle?

Comment: The array you've provided isn't sorted - if you sort the array every time you push an element to it, then it'll be at the right place :)

Comment: Is it better to add the input to the array first and then display it or directly display the array and put the input somewhere in there?

Comment: Where should the value be added in the array? And is the array always sorted?
For example, where should 32 be added in the following array: [2,12,42,612,3,13,43]

Comment: Oh i understand there is a mistake in my logic...yes the array must be sorted and then the input must been added to the right place like array element < input < array element

Comment: Thump up for clear question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sjoy8p59/2/)**.

You can do it using `push()` to add your input to the Array, and use simple function `sortNumber()` to sort it.

**JS :**

```
var numbers = [2, 4, 8, 12, 42, 120, 612, 69];
var input = 32;

numbers.push(input); //add 32 to the array

function sortNumber(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}

numbers.sort(sortNumber); //Sort Array
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = numbers.join(","); //Display result
```

---

```js
var numbers = [2, 4, 8, 12, 42, 120, 612, 69];
var input = 32;

numbers.push(input); //add 32 to the array

function sortNumber(a,b) {
  return a - b;
}

numbers.sort(sortNumber);

alert(numbers.join(","));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just sort them:

```js
var numbers = [2, 4, 8, 12, 42, 120, 612, 69];
var input = 32;
numbers.push(input)
numbers.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = numbers.join(', ');
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/sjoy8p59/3/

```
var numbers = [2, 4, 8, 12, 42, 120, 612, 69];
var input = 32;
var flag = false;
var output = "";

for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (numbers[i] < input || flag == true) {
        output += numbers[i]+", ";
    } else {
        output += input + ", ";
        flag = true;
        i--
    }
}
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
```

I edited your jsfiddle with minimal edit to your code, although the sort methods look cleaner.